# Set suffix for module resolution in Meteor

Tags: meteor, build, webpack

I'm trying to include the [bcoin](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin) library in my Meteor project. bcoin uses two type of modules, `<module>.js` and `<module>-browser.js`, depending whether one is building a node app or a browser app. In my case I need to import bcoin in the frontend part of my project, but a normal `import bcoin from 'bcoin'` resolves the module `bcoin.js` by default. Even if I use `import bcoin from 'bcoin/lib/bcoin-browser'` the file `bcoin-browser.js` will require other `.js` files rather than their `-browser.js` variant. The [webpack configuration](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/blob/master/webpack.browser.js#L18) uses the directive

```
 resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['-browser.js', '.js', '.json']
  },
```

is there something similar in Meteor?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you meant `import bcoin from 'bcoin/lib/bcoin-browser'`?

Comment: I edited the import statement, thanks.